# Solving integral of $\log(-\log(1-u))...$

Tags: integration, logarithms

I have an integral to solve which is based on two parameters $i$ and $n$, where $i,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $1 \le i \le n$ and the integral is,

$$
k(i,n) = n! \int_0^1 \log(-\log(1-u)) \frac{ u^{i-1}(1-u)^{n-i}}{(i-1)!(n-i)!} \mathrm{du}
$$
For any given $i$ and $n$, this integral has a solution, but I fail to see the general expression for any $i$ and any $n$.

Comment: Also, I have the vague feeling that I saw this integral somewhere before. If it is documented in some source, the reference would be appreciated. d.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bring the constants outside first,
$$\frac{n!}{(i-1)!(n-i)!}\int_{0}^{1}\ln(-\ln(1- u)) u^{i-1} (1-u)^{n-i} du$$
The constant terms can be rewritten in terms of combinations. But let's see how to solve the integral,
$$\int_{0}^{1}\ln(-\ln (1-u)) u^{i-1} (1-u)^{n-i} du$$
Substitute $ x=1-u \implies dx=-du$
$$\int_{0}^{1}\ln(-\ln x) (1-x)^{i-1} x^{n-i} dx$$
Put, $x=\frac{1}{t} \implies dx=\frac{-1}{t^2} dt$
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\ln\ln (t) \left(1-\frac{1}{t}\right)^{i-1} t^{i-n} t^{-2} dt$$
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\ln\ln (t) (t-1)^{i-1} t^{-n-1} dt$$
Substitute $s=\ln t \implies dt=e^{s}ds$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln( s) (e^{s}-1)^{i-1} e^{-sn} ds$$
Using the binomial theorem we have,
$$\sum_{a=0}^{i-1} \binom{i-1}{a}(-1)^{i-1-a}\int_{0}^{\infty} \ln(s) e^{-s(n-a)} \mathrm{ds} $$
Substitute $v=s(n-a) \implies ds=\frac{dv}{n-a} $
$$\sum_{a=0}^{i-1}\frac{1}{n-a}\binom{i-1}{a}(-1)^{i-1-a}\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln(\frac{v}{n-a}) e^{-v} dv$$
$$\sum_{a=0}^{i-1}\frac{1}{n-a}\binom{i-1}{a}(-1)^{i-1-a}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln(v) e^{-v} dv-\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln(n-a) e^{-v} dv \right)$$
Second integral is pretty easy to evaluate,but the first integral is somewhat special, it's the derivative of [gamma function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) evaluate at $1$ i.e $\Gamma'(1)=-\gamma$. Where, $\gamma$ denotes the Euler mascheroni constant

I believe you can do the else, which involves the summation only.

Comment: In the first formula you like the argument of $\ln$ to be $1-u$ and not $u$.

Comment: @Gary, thanks for pointing out. It's a typo, fixed it though:)

Comment: Thanks @2isevenprime. I am stuck at the step involving the binomial theorem: How did you go from $(e^s-1)^{i-1}$ to $\sum_{a=0}^{i-1} \binom{i-1}{a}e^{ks}$? Where did the minus sign go?

Comment: @Denis Cousineau, thanks for pointing out. I fixed it. It was a typo

Comment: @2isevenprime : Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think that a possible way is:

1. Change variables $1-u=e^{-t}$;
2. Use $\ln(t)=\int_1^t\frac{1}{x}dx$;
3. Reverse the order of integration of the double integral;
4. Use $z=e^{-(n-i+1)t}$ with [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) to obtain a (finite) sum expression in $x$;
5. Integrate with respect to $x$.

You will probably arrive at something like a (finite) sum of terms involving the [Exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral). So (I'm guessing) this explain why in some cases the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant) shows up.

Comment: Thanks, you had all the correct steps. However, @2isevenprime 's solution was more detailed.